# Why does this grammar book say there is a tense problem in "No one...wishes that we had...homework each night"?

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

> No one in my history class wishes that we had more homework each night.

This is from a 4th grader's grammar book and says it doesn't have a proper verb tense.

I don't get it. Can anybody help?

Comment: I think the intention is to switch "had" for "have", because "each night" sounds like it's currently happening (although it doesn't have to mean that)

Comment: Is this from an electronic book or a paper book? Could you please provide the exact wording of the error message or error description?

Comment: It is a multiple choice question from a paper book, that requires to choose one with a proper verb tense out of  4 choices given. This sentence was not a correct choice and there was no explanation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no error, at least not at 4th-grade grammar level.

There is a slight tension between the meaning of "wish" (which seems in this context to be a hope for the future) and "had" in the past tense.  However such constructions are common. You can wish, counterfactually, for something in the past.  Therefore this is not an error.

There is a slight tension between "Nobody" (third person) and "we" first person.  But again, this is not an error.

Comment: The second point is hardly any tension at all, since one often wishes for things about other people.

Comment: Just curious, the use of "tension" in your answer, does it relate in any way to "tense"?

Comment: @justhalf, ultimately both "tension" and "tense" come from the Proto-Indo-European root *ten, "to stretch", but via different paths. "Tension" is literally "stretching". "Tense" in the grammatical sense is related to "tempus", "a portion of time", which is related to *ten only via a few jumps. Try searching for the words in an etymological dictionary, like the Online Etymology Dictionary.

Comment: "Had" is the past tense of the verb "have", but that doesn't necessarily mean it refers to something in the past. When it indicates a counterfactual situation, as it does here, it can actually refer to the present, or to something that apparently can't be changed even in the future. You'd need to use "had had" to refer to a counterfactual past: "No one wishes that we had had more homework."

Comment: Oh, thanks Alan, sorry I wasn't clear  I mean what does "tension" here mean? It's not wrong, so what is it?

Answer (score 0):

'No-one **wished**...' would work better, if it was all in the past.

If it's in the present, then 'that we **have** more...' fits better.

However, at that grade level, it's not screaming out as wrong, but could be matched better.

Comment: I disagree. *"No one wishes that we have more homework" would be incorrect. We're talking about a counterfactual situation, so we need to use "had".  "No one wishes that we had more homework" is correct, and the grammar book is wrong.